# JFrame issue (close focus)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a very basic experience with java and have 2 questions.

> Question 1: I have a button that opens a new JFrame, which works
> perfectly. On the second `iJFrame` I have a button which -should- make
> the app hide (lose focus).

I have looked around and found that this is easily done with `JFrameName".setFocusableWindowState(false`

The problem is I can't seem to be able to name the current jframe JFrame I'm in, so I can't call the function. I usually call the JFrame I've made into view with this in the public main of my starting code :

```
JFrameName newframe = new JFrameName();
newframe.setVisible(true);
```

Where exactly do I declare the name of the `JFrameName` instance I've made in my `JFrame` class so iI can call the `setFocusableWindowState` function?

> Question 2: The above question is done because I want to link a
> keyboard shortcut to a button. this keyboard shortcut should then be
> used - within another window, not the java application. my question:
> can iI manually define keyboard shortcuts (for example
> control+alt+delete) or (control+f1) within java so my program will
> execute the button hits for me?

Comment: Answer 1) Write a method in the first JFrame class that calls the setFocusableWindowState method.  Call that method from your second JFrame.  Better yet, rework your application so it only uses one JFrame.  One JFrame is a much better experience for your user.  Answer 2) I have no idea if you can pass a keyboard shortcut to another application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question wholly. But maybe this will help.

Instead of making a JFrame, since it is not a "final" class, you also have the option of creating a new class that extends JFrame. The new class can have additional methods. One of those methods could be one to allow you to tell the new JFrame the name of the JFrame that you want to return focus to.

As far as I know, it's possible to create a KeyListener that can tell if a shift or alt or control key are pressed. I'd have to research the details to know for sure. A good starting point should be the tutorial [How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

> I have a button which -should- make the app hide (lose focus).

If you want the window to hide then normally you would use:

```
window.setVisible( false ).
```

This is the opposite of showing the window.

The setWindowFocusableState(false) will still keep the window visible, you just won't be able to make any component on the window have focus.

> The problem is I can't seem to be able to name the current jframe JFrame I'm in

That information can be found by coding the following in the `ActionListener` of your button:

```
JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( button );
window.setVisible( false );
```